# jQuery powered fixed positioned div - on page scroll disappears in Firefox, works fine in Chrome, IE, Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

[Here](http://bit.ly/S9eJ87) I have a div on the bottom of right sidebar that supposed to act in this way:

1. When you scroll down the page and div reaches the top of the browser screen, it's class changes and it will get fixed on top of the screen untill you reach to the bottom of div's parent element.
2. Once the bottom of div reaches the bottom of parent element, its class changes back to non-fixed position.

Now to the problem:

For some reason in Firefox once div reaches the top of parent element it disappears, while in Chrome, IE and Safari it stays visible.

How can I prevent div from disappearing in Firefox?

You can find all the necessary code here: http://bit.ly/S9eJ87 .

Comment: Really? You linked us back to the page? with a bit.ly? Dude...that's just...vote to close. We're people here to help, we're not developers that work for free. I'm not digging through your markup to find the relevant objects. If you can't be bothered to go through the time to find it for us so that we can help with your extremely localized issue, then you'll get the same treatment in kind.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I can make a jsfiddle for you if using firebug is not one of your stronger sides. If you can help me fix the issue I don't mind paying either, pm for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of a known issue with Firefox (and I think some versions of IE) not correctly setting the height of a nested table which has the height set to 100%.

On Chrome, $('#col12').height() is 1102.  On Firefox, it is 0.

So as a workaround, you can change this line:

```
else if ($(this).scrollTop() + $el.height() 
  < $el.parent().offset().top + $el.parent().height())
```

to:

```
else if ($(window).scrollTop() + $el.height() 
  < $el.parent().offset().top + ($('.content2').height() - $('#fullsize td:first').height()))
```

If you give some better ids to the elements, you can replace the td:first selector.

Basically what is happening is this:

- Your main content has a left column with one row, and a right column with 2 rows.
- The bottom row of the right column should be max height, but it's not.
- So to figure out what that height should have been, take the height of the left column, and subtract the height of the top row of the right column.

Let me know if that's not clear and I'll try and update my answer.

mkm

Comment: Brilliant! This fixed the problem I've been struggling to fix for a long time now. You are a genius sir!